# Android application occurs twice in main menu

Tags: android

I wrote an android application and after I run it, it occurs twice in main menu. I mean, there are two icons for this application, but only one could be open.

If I deinstall this application, I find only one entry in the application list.

It's the same, if application's running in simulator or on phone. And I don't have this problem with my other applications.

Any ideas???

Thanks a lot in advance.

Mur

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you see your app twice, you either have two intents in your manifest file with the LAUNCHER category (make sure you have only one), or you changed the name of your package/class throughout the development process. Since you said that uninstalling it removes one copy, I'm tempted to suspect the latter.

Comment: Not to resurrect an old thread, but I ran into this issue and fixing the LAUNCHER `intent-filter` in the manifest fixed it. I'm pretty sure when using updated versions of the Android SDK in Eclipse, when you use ADT to create a new activity for you, it automatically creates it in the manifest for your convenience but it defaults it to intent.category.LAUNCHER for some reason. Just in case anybody else has this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If your project uses library projects, check in the AndroidManifest.xml of each library project.

That's where I found the second intent with the LAUNCHER category.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but created slightly differently. I had the main activity and a second activity to complete OAuth validation. The scheme I used for the OAuth callback was the same as the app's package name. i.e. I used `com.example.app` as both the package name, as well as the 2nd intent's scheme and my callback URL for OAuth.

Since the package name matched the OAuth callback, it was auto-added as an option to select. Once I changed the OAuth callback and 2nd intent's scheme to something else the app opened without showing me multiple options.