# Android App Installs Twice

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android application occurs twice in main menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650580/android-application-occurs-twice-in-main-menu)

I'm using the android emulator to test my app and it's installing twice and the icon is duplicated in the application menu.  Clicking on either Icon takes me to the same activity within my app.  Any ideas on why two icons are showing up in the app menu?  I've tried clearing and starting with a new emulator and the same things happens.  I checked the manifest file and I only have one activity listed as launcher. Thanks

Comment: did you change the application packaga name after setting up a new project?

Comment: Yes, I did?  How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Android uniquely identifies a application with the application package name. When you change the name of the apps package name and try to install it on a device, android will look for a app with the same package name and if it exists it will update the exisitng aplication otherwise it will consider it a new applicaton. This is from the google documentation about updating apps

> If the package name and signing
>   certificate do not match those of the existing version, Market will
>   consider it a new application, publish it as such, and will not offer
>   it to existing users as an update.

So once you decided on the package name, never change it.

This is a link to a application in the android market

```
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.quintetsolutions
```

You can notice at the end of the url that the appliations package name is used to refer it in the market.