# Android app with two different apks

Tags: android

I am facing a strange problem on the android app.When i run the app in emulator it runs the app properly but when checked on the installed app list on the 
emulator, it shows two apps with same name "simplifimed" (my app name) installed.When clicked on the other app icon it runs the app separately but shows very old version screens.I have tried uninstalling both the apps and tried running the app again same two apps are installed.

Previously my app was working fine but for upload to google play store we have to change the package name.So we have changed the package name from 
**com.example.simplifimed**
to
**com.medical_ocr_app.simplifimed**
used Android Tools->Rename application package from eclipse

I have checked the manifest and everywhere new package name is added properly.Also new application works fine without any error in emulator.Only problem it installs two apps (different apk)
Can anyone help me with this?

My andriod manifest file is as follows,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.medical_ocr_appln.simplifimed"
   android:versionCode="4"
   android:versionName="1.4" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  

<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" /> -->

<!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Permission to vibrate 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<permission
    android:name="com.example.simplifimed.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.simplifimed.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />  
android:debuggable="false"
-->

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppCompatTheme"
    android:testOnly="false"        
     >

    <activity
        android:name="com.medical_ocr_appln.simplifimed.DashboardActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/rx" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>   

    <!--  Login Activity DashboardActivity MainActivity MedListActivity -->
    <activity
        android:label="My Schedule" 
        android:name="com.medical_ocr_appln.simplifimed.TabBar"></activity>


    <!--  Login Activity DashboardActivity MainActivity MedListActivity -->
    <activity
        android:label="Login Account" 
        android:name="com.medical_ocr_appln.simplifimed.LoginActivity"></activity>

    <!--  Register Activity -->
    <activity
        android:label="Register New Account" 
        android:name="com.medical_ocr_appln.simplifimed.RegisterActivity"></activity>   

    <!--  Edit contact Activity -->
    <activity
        android:label="Edit Contact" 
        android:name="com.medical_ocr_appln.simplifimed.EditContact"></activity> 

    <!--  My Notifications Activity -->
    <activity
        android:label="My Notifications" 
        android:name="com.medical_ocr_appln.simplifimed.myNotiifcations"></activity>     

    <!--  Photo Intent Activity -->
    <activity
        android:label="PhotoIntentActivity" 
        android:name="com.medical_ocr_appln.simplifimed.PhotoIntentActivity"></activity>   

     <!--  MedConfirmation Activity -->
    <activity
        android:label="MedConfirmation" 
        android:name="com.medical_ocr_appln.simplifimed.MedConfirmation"></activity>   

    <!--  Save Med to DB Activity -->
    <activity
        android:label="Save Medicine" 
        android:name="com.medical_ocr_appln.simplifimed.SaveMedToDB"></activity> 

    <!--  FirstLast Activity -->
    <activity
        android:label="First Last Dose Activity" 
        android:name="com.medical_ocr_appln.simplifimed.FirstLastDose"></activity>  

    <!--  ChangePassword Activity -->
    <activity
        android:label="Change Password Activity" 
        android:name="com.medical_ocr_appln.simplifimed.ChangePassword"></activity>  

    <!--  Password Reset Activity -->
    <activity
        android:label="Password Reset Activity" 
        android:name="com.medical_ocr_appln.simplifimed.PasswordReset"></activity>

     <!--  NewContactActivity Activity -->
    <activity
        android:label="Add New Contact" 
        android:name="com.medical_ocr_appln.simplifimed.NewContactActivity"></activity>

     <!--  NewContactActivity Activity -->
    <activity
        android:label="Set Notify Reminder" 
        android:name="com.medical_ocr_appln.simplifimed.SetNotifyReminder"></activity>    


</application>
```

Thanks,
Sangram

Comment: check your build gradle

Comment: I am using eclipse , checked in bin only one "simplifimed.apk" file is there

Comment: please post your manifest

Comment: Check this.It might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650580/android-application-occurs-twice-in-main-menu

Comment: I have checked the post, there is no duplicate intents in manifest so that is not the case..and other case  "you changed the name of your package/class throughout the development process"..yes i have renamed the package..so what to do for this case?

Comment: Try to run your emulator with a memory wipe. By default the emulator uses a snapshot. It looks like the old apk is installed along side the new one. Or just use a new emulator to test this hypothesis.

Comment: The emulator i am using currently does not have snapshot option checked...tried new one also but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting my solution which may help some one..
Since i am not able to get any solution for my problem i carry out the rename package once again with following steps and it worked for me,

1. Go and edit the manifest and gen folder.
2. Remove every old package name in the manifest and in gen folder
3. Put instead of the old package name, the new package name in every location inside the manifest. You might have classes (Activities that is) that need direct package name references.
4. Save the manifest.
5. Then right click the package name inside the project.
6. Select "Refactor".
7. Select "Rename".
8. Type the new package name.
9. Select "update references".
10. Press OK and you're done and watch out also what should be done to replace the new name.
11. Don't forget to also update the layout XML files with the new package name. You might have a custom View. Look for them.

Thanks..